# The location of "respectively"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I want to combine two sentences:

> where upper(A) is the upper bound of A when (34), (35), and (39) are satisfied and upper(B) is the upper bound of B when (34), (35), and (39) are satisfied.

I rewrite it as:

> where upper(A) and upper(B) are the upper bounds of A and B when (34), (35), and (39) are satisfied, respectively.

Is this expression (especially the location of "respectively") right? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The meaning with your sentence is :
upper(A) and upper(B) are upper bounds of A when 34 and 35 are satisfied and upper(A) and upper(B) are upper bounds of B when 39 is satisfied

IMO, it should be

> where upper(A) and upper(B) are the upper bounds of A and B, respectively, when (34), (35), and (39) are satisfied.